# simplexml_load_string fails to load xml from a url

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract XML data from a URL.  It's not an XML file, but a response based on a request string.

```
$url = "http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice?eligibilityType=Property&requestString=<?xml version='1.0'?><Eligibility xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='/var/lib/tomcat5/webapps/eligibility/Eligibilitywsdl.xsd'><PropertyRequest StreetAddress1='".$street."' StreetAddress2='' StreetAddress3='' City='".$city."' State='".$state."' County='' Zip='".$zip."' Program='RBS'></PropertyRequest></Eligibility>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url); // requires allow_url_fopen to be on
$elg = (string)$xml->Property[Eligibility];

var_dump($xml);
```

The data I want looks like this:

```
<Eligibility>
    <Adjusted AnnualIncome="" TotalDeduction="" AdjustedIncome="" ElderlyDeduction="" YoungDeduction="">
    </Adjusted>
    <Section502Guaranted MaximumAdjusted="" Eligible="">
    </Section502Guaranted>
    <Section502Direct MaximumAdjusted="" Eligible="">
    </Section502Direct>
    <Property Eligibility="UnableToVerifyAddress" MapURL="http://rdgdwe.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibilitymaps/index.jsp?app=RBSIELG&ADDRESS=392 Spruce east alton&STATE=IL&ZIP=62024"/>
    <ErrorResponse EngineId="" HostName="" MaxSeverity="" LogFile="" Class="" Module="" Severity="" Time="">
        <Message Code="" Type="" Text=""/>
    </ErrorResponse>
</Eligibility>
```

What I'm getting back looks like this:

```
bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false) bool(false)
```

I have not clue why it's doing this.  No errors are posting either.

Comment: `simplexml_load_string` returns false on failure - it can't access the url you're trying to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
$url = "http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice?eligibilityType=Property&requestString=<?xml version='1.0'?><Eligibility xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='/var/lib/tomcat5/webapps/eligibility/Eligibilitywsdl.xsd'><PropertyRequest StreetAddress1='".$street."' StreetAddress2='' StreetAddress3='' City='".$city."' State='".$state."' County='' Zip='".$zip."' Program='RBS'></PropertyRequest></Eligibility>";
$url_arr = explode( 'requestString=', $url );
$xml = simplexml_load_string( $url_arr[ 1 ] ); // requires allow_url_fopen to be on
$elg = (string)$xml->Property[Eligibility];

var_dump($xml);
```

Basically, I just explode the $url you have given so that the well-formed xml will be isolated in $url_arr[ 1 ]

Comment: That looks unlikely to be useful to the OP - http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice is an xml response

Comment: Why? it works. Before it shows bool(false) and throws warnings, after it works and shows var_dump output..

Comment: because requestString is an argument he's passing TO that url. A url you aren't querying. It's a possibility there's a url accidentally prepended to the desired xml string - but seems unlikely, especially since the variable is named `$url` and not `$xmlString` or similar

Comment: Ah, I thought based on the question he needed to isolate the xml in the url, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

`simplexml_load_string()` requires a well-formed XML string, not a URL.  You might want to try `simplexml_load_file()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove from $url the following:

```
http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice?eligibilityType=Property&requestString=
```

since the simplexml_load_string function takes a well-formed XML string and you have an URL before the starting  tag

Comment: ...so how would I tell the script where to load the XML from?  That URL is what generates the return XML response.

Comment: I misunderstood your question.

Try entering the full URL you have in the $url variable into a browser (and then view the page source), so you can see if that URL actually returns something valid (like the valid XML code you need to supply the simplexml_load_string() or simplexml_load_file() function)